# HTML5 Boilerplate <head> script & Designing for mobile

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

Recently I've come across HTML5 Boilerplate and love it! However there is one part of it I don't understand.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Paul Irish says that we can use this instead of Conditional stylesheets and CSS hacks. Does anyone have some experience in this as as many times as I read his blog about it I still can't get it to make sense.

Right now I'm using CSS3 Media Queries however it's not working in IE at all and I'm just a lucky one and CSS3-mediaqueries.js file (or something like that) AND the respond.js file just don't work for me. So I decided that conditional comments or specific stylesheets were for me but I remembered about this setup yet really don't know how to use it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These are what are called *conditional comments*, as you've surmised. They're not part of any standard at all.

They're a funny thing IE does - it actually parses the text of what's supposed to be inactive data! But it should work.

The way you use this is simple: If you are using IE < 7, then you style your `blah` elements for a `.ie6 blah`. A more concrete example: let's say you want your hyperlinks to be red when the user is in IE8, and green otherwise. Here's some CSS:

```
a {
    color: green;
}

.ie8 a {
    color: red;
}
```

Since the "`a` which is a descendent of an element having class `ie8`" is more specific than the "any `a`", the latter applies and in IE8 the links will be red. This logic only applies to IE8 because that's the only case in which the conditional comment for IE8 is interpreted as part of the HTML (rather than commented out).

The only other bit which might be confusing is that last line, where you have a `-->` *inside* the comment block: this means that a browser totally ignoring the conditional comments will still see the HTML in the last block (along with IE > 9 and non-IE-but-still-interpreting-conditional-comments browsers).

Comment: Would this be a good way to style for IE instead of my media queries? Cause as it is now, if you go to my site in any IE version (except IE 9 of course) you see the styling for the mobile version. Not sure why. Might you be able to help me out with this and give me advice on the appropriate method to use for my site if I give you the link to my site so you can see what it might be doing? This is my first time using HTML 5 and style for mobile and tablet users so it's a big confusing.

Comment: @AmberGoodwin This is a fine way to style for IE. I don't know enough about IE-specific behavior (I always code for W3C standards) to tell you why your site is being badly behaved, beyond advising you to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first thing in the document. Sorry.

Comment: That's okay then. I appreciate the answer. I'll go full throttle ahead. Thanks!